# Subtract date days from number (except weekend days) using apex class

Tags: apex, date, calendar

I need to result like this,

> Date__c = Date_one__c - number__c;
>
> // 8/14/2015 = 9/1/2015 - 12
>
> result(Date__c) must be in working days (Monday to Friday)

i have tried so much ways like adddays() etc.

```
if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate) {
    for(Deal__c d : Trigger.New){

            d.Mfg_Cycle_Time_Target__c = 0;

            if(d.Parts__c == true){
                d.Mfg_Cycle_Time_Target__c += 2;
            }
            if(d.Welding__c == true){
                d.Mfg_Cycle_Time_Target__c += 1;
            }
            if(d.Galv__c == true){
                d.Mfg_Cycle_Time_Target__c += 12;
            }
            if(d.Finishing__c == true){
                d.Mfg_Cycle_Time_Target__c += 2;
            }/*else{
                d.Mfg_Cycle_Time_Target__c += 0 + 1;
            }*/
            if(d.Aluminum_Required__c > 0){
                d.Mfg_Cycle_Time_Target__c += 2;
            }
            if(d.All_Wood__c == true){
                d.Mfg_Cycle_Time_Target__c += 9;
            }
            if(d.CS_Stair_Cap__c > 0){
                d.Mfg_Cycle_Time_Target__c += 2;
            }
            if(d.CS_Stair_Cap__c > 0){
                d.Mfg_Cycle_Time_Target__c += 2;
            }
            if(d.Straight_Stair_Cap__c > 0){
                d.Mfg_Cycle_Time_Target__c += 5;
            }
            if(d.Welded_Line_Rail_Cap__c > 0){
                d.Mfg_Cycle_Time_Target__c += 2;
            }

            d.Release_Date_Target__c = d.Estimated_Ship_Week__c - ((d.Mfg_Cycle_Time_Target__c.intValue())/7)*2;

    }
}
```

Comment: Date.addDays(int) might helpful. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_addDays

Comment: Have you looked into using [BusinessHours](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm)?

Comment: No. i think it should not work with my code.

Comment: @Nihar - Business hours are your best bet. Then all you have to to is one method businessHours.diff() to get the number of hours and divide by 86400000 to get the number of days. Set Sat and sun as non business days, then 24 hours for mon-fri. Much easier than what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution with below code and it will executed perfect.

```
   public static Date calculateWeekDaysforReleaseDateTarget(Date EstimatedDate, Integer targetDays){
            Date ReleaseDate = EstimatedDate.addDays(-targetDays);

            Integer nonWorkingDays = 0;
            Integer currentDay;
            for(Integer i=0; i <= ReleaseDate.daysBetween(EstimatedDate); i++) {
                currentDay = Math.MOD(Date.newInstance(1990,1,7).daysBetween(ReleaseDate.addDays(i)),7);
                if(currentDay == 6 || currentDay == 0) {
                    nonWorkingDays++;
                }
            }

            ReleaseDate = ReleaseDate.addDays(-nonWorkingDays);

            Datetime dt = DateTime.newInstance(ReleaseDate.year(), ReleaseDate.month(), ReleaseDate.day());
            if(dt.format('E') == 'Sat'){
                ReleaseDate = ReleaseDate.adddays(-1);
            }
            else if(dt.format('E') == 'Sun'){
                ReleaseDate = ReleaseDate.adddays(-2);
            }

            return ReleaseDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first subtract days using ADDDays method

```
Date myDate = Date.newInstance(1960, 2, 17);
Date newDate = mydate.addDays(-2);
```

Now find weekstart day of current week toStartOfWeek()

> Returns the start of the week for the Date that called the method,
>   depending on the context user's locale.

```
Date myDate = Date.today();
Date weekStart = myDate.toStartofWeek();
```

Now find difference between your current date and weekstart days. if it is less then 5. then it is a week days or if greater then 5 then subtract extra days using add days and you will get you expected result. Hope it solve your problem.

Comment: not getting the exact value

Comment: @Nihar what error you are getting here?

Comment: not any kind of error. but i don't know how i can implement this to my code.

Comment: follow all steps first subtract then find week day and based on week day add or subtract extra day.

Comment: Tushar, Please have look into my code. i have updated my question